# Error itgengpr020 / itgenuty427 on log on to Invantive Control for Excel with Exact Online

Tags: invantive-control, exact-online

When I log on to Exact Online from within Invantive Control for Excel, I get the following error:

> There are 1.005 available partitions. This exceeds the maximum allowed
>   number of 1.000 partitions.

Or as shown in Dutch in the error message, including the top of stack error message:

> Een verbinding met de database 'Exact Online\Exact Online (nl)' kon niet worden opgebouwd als gebruiker ...
>   There are 1.005 available partitions. This exceeds the maximum allowed
>   number of 1.000 partitions.

After this, I am not connected. How can I log on?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've included the original Dutch text too.

Answer (score 0):

On a non-enterprise license, you may have to access at most 1.000 partitions such as Exact Online divisions, NMBRS companies or Salesforce orgs, irrespective of the actual number used.

Typically on Exact Online you have more division access assigned than necessary.

Best is to first withdraw rights for the user on archived divisions. You can find them by using the following [query](https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/invantive-eol-provider-exactonlinerest-system-systemdivisions.html) after withdrawing some rights:

```
select *
from   systemdivisions
```

and then filter on status = 2.

After that, you might be able to get below 1.000 by withdrawing privileges.